# How to space adjustment in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview

I am working on Gridview. Code work fine but it display right side space to view.
how can i adjust space in gridview.my problem is exactly below.

[image]

My code xml file code:

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridExam"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

*Thanks in advance
Your answer would be appreciated.*

Comment: Please post the layout xml file. Also, consider using RecyclerView, it is easier to maintain and customize :)

Comment: I updated code in my question.

Comment: Did you add margin on the right of your item ?

Comment: I wann Item utilize space of right size & display as filled.

Comment: @Vasant Try adding this `android:listSelector="@null"` to your  `Grid View`.

Comment: @Vasant : bhai have you tried that change what i suggested ?

Comment: yes i did,but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Give marginLeft to your GridView.

Comment: Add this suggestions always in comments. other then give brief answers always.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>
```

Comment: it work but  if i give horizontals space=2 then in will not reduce space.mean it display some space on right side.i want only 2dp size arround item.